# Swift 2: struct thread-safety

Tags: ios, macos, swift, grand-central-dispatch

In my swift practice, I wrote simple struct named `OrderedSet`.

I tried `OrderedSet` to be a thread-safe with GCD serial queue.

But it’s not working. The test result is unstable. I expected something like:

```
20:[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

but received something like like

```
2:[3, 19]
```

here is playground code:

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

struct OrderedSet<T: Equatable> {
    mutating func append(e: T) {
        dispatch_sync(q) {
            if !self.__elements.contains(e) {
                self.__elements.append(e)
            }
        }
    }
    var elements: [T] {
        var elements: [T] = []
        dispatch_sync(q) {
            elements = self.__elements
        }
        return elements
    }
    var count: Int {
        var ret = 0
        dispatch_sync(q) {
            ret = self.__elements.count
        }
        return ret
    }
    private var __elements: [T] = []
    private let q = dispatch_queue_create("OrderedSet.private.serial.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
}
extension OrderedSet: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var text = ""
        dispatch_sync(q) {
            text = "\(self.__elements.count):\(self.__elements)"
        }
        return text
    }
}

// Test code
let globalQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
let group = dispatch_group_create()

var testSet = OrderedSet<Int>()
for i in 0..<20 {
    dispatch_group_async(group, globalQueue) {
        testSet.append(i)
    }
}
dispatch_group_notify(group, globalQueue) {
    print("\(testSet)") // unstable result
}

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```

I’ve checked below:

It’s OK if defined `OrderdSet` as a class (not struct).

It’s OK if using semaphore instead of using serial queue.

I would like to know the reason why the pair of struct and serial queue is unstable.

---- updated

I got the expected result with these.

1. class instead of struct

   ```
   import Foundation
   import XCPlayground

   class OrderedSet<T: Equatable> {
       func append(e: T) {
           dispatch_sync(q) {
               if !self.__elements.contains(e) {
                   self.__elements.append(e)
               }
           }
       }
       var elements: [T] {
           var elements: [T] = []
           dispatch_sync(q) {
               elements = self.__elements
           }
           return elements
       }
       var count: Int {
           var ret = 0
           dispatch_sync(q) {
               ret = self.__elements.count
           }
           return ret
       }
       private var __elements: [T] = []
       private let q = dispatch_queue_create("OrderedSet.private.serial.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
   }
   extension OrderedSet: CustomStringConvertible {
       var description: String {
           var text = ""
           dispatch_sync(q) {
               text = "\(self.__elements.count):\(self.__elements)"
           }
           return text
       }
   }

   // Test code
   let globalQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
   let group = dispatch_group_create()

   var testSet = OrderedSet<Int>()
   for i in 0..<20 {
       dispatch_group_async(group, globalQueue) {
           testSet.append(i)
       }
   }
   dispatch_group_notify(group, globalQueue) {
       print("\(testSet)") // It's OK
   }

   XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
   ```
2. semaphore instead of serial queue

   ```
   import Foundation
   import XCPlayground

   struct OrderedSet<T: Equatable> {
       mutating func append(e: T) {
           dispatch_semaphore_wait(s, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
           if !self.__elements.contains(e) {
               self.__elements.append(e)
           }
           dispatch_semaphore_signal(s)
       }
       var elements: [T] {
           var elements: [T] = []
           dispatch_semaphore_wait(s, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
           elements = self.__elements
           dispatch_semaphore_signal(s)
           return elements
       }
       var count: Int {
           var ret = 0
           dispatch_semaphore_wait(s, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
           ret = self.__elements.count
           dispatch_semaphore_signal(s)
           return ret
       }
       private var __elements: [T] = []
       private let s = dispatch_semaphore_create(1)
   }
   extension OrderedSet: CustomStringConvertible {
       var description: String {
           var text = ""
           dispatch_semaphore_wait(s, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
           text = "\(self.__elements.count):\(self.__elements)"
           dispatch_semaphore_signal(s)
           return text
       }
   }

   // Test code
   let globalQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
   let group = dispatch_group_create()

   var testSet = OrderedSet<Int>()
   for i in 0..<20 {
       dispatch_group_async(group, globalQueue) {
           testSet.append(i)
       }
   }
   dispatch_group_notify(group, globalQueue) {
       print("\(testSet)") // It's OK
   }

   XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
   ```
3. serial queue with OrderdSet itself.

   ```
   import Foundation
   import XCPlayground

   struct OrderedSet<T: Equatable> {
       mutating func append(e: T) {
           if !self.__elements.contains(e) {
               self.__elements.append(e)
           }
       }
       var elements: [T] {
           return self.__elements
       }
       var count: Int {
           return self.__elements.count
       }
       private var __elements: [T] = []
   }
   extension OrderedSet: CustomStringConvertible {
       var description: String {
           return "\(self.__elements.count):\(self.__elements)"
       }
   }

   // Test code
   let globalQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
   let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("serial", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

   let group = dispatch_group_create()

   var testSet = OrderedSet<Int>()
   for i in 0..<20 {
       dispatch_group_async(group, globalQueue) {
           dispatch_sync(serialQueue) {
               testSet.append(i)
           }
       }
   }
   dispatch_group_notify(group, serialQueue) {
       print("\(testSet)") // It's OK
   }

   XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
   ```

Comment: So, what is the symptom?  [how to ask on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: my expected result is like "20:[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]" but result is like "2:[3, 19]".

Comment: @tom.e.kid Please share the testing code as well

Comment: @Kametrixom added some code I got expected result. thanks

Comment: @tom.e.kid Regarding your expected result, you shouldn't necessary expect them to be in order (because you're adding them from that global queue), but I agree that I would have expected to see all of the elements in the ordered set. Good question.

Comment: @Rob You're right. I don't need expect them to be in order. thank you.

Comment: I don't sure , but every time, when you modify struct, struct do copy (copy on write) themselves else first time

Answer (score 3):

This code will capture **current value** of `testSet`:

```
dispatch_group_async(group, globalQueue) {
    testSet.append(i) // `testSet` inside the closure will be a copy of the `testSet` variable outside 
}
```

After the execution of the closure, the value of the inside `testSet` will be copied to the outside `testSet` variable.

Imagine a concurrent world:

- 10 closures are running simultaneously, capturing the initial value of the outside `testSet`, which is "0:[]".
- Once finished, 10 copy of `testSet`s inside closures try to copy back to the only outside `testSet`. However, there is only one winner, say, current value of the outside `testSet` is "1:[3]".
- Yet another round start, capturing current value of the outside `testSet` which is "1:[3]", appending `i`, and copying back, yielding the weird result, say, "2:[3, 19]"

In your updated case 1, changing `OrderedSet` to class, things are pretty straight forward, `testSet` is captured by reference, and all the threads are sharing the same object.

In your updated case 3, by using serial queue, I guess every appending and copying back operation is serial, so you yield a perfect ordered set.

Case 2 is more complicated. Actually I haven't figure out what's going on under the hood. And I think it's more about a implementation detail of the swift compiler and may change over different swift versions.  It seems like semaphore is a reference type, thus all the copy of the 'testSet's are sharing the same semaphore. I guess complier decide to do some optimization in this case and make all the copy of the `testSet`s' `__element` point to the same array. So the result contains all the 0..<20 elements but the order is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening when `dispatch_sync` is used inside the struct is  that `self` is implicitly captured by the closure as an `inout` parameter.

That means that a copy is modified, which then replaces the outer `self` on return. So there's multiple concurrent copies of self being mutated, then clobbering the original.

In the semaphores case there is no closure so there's no capture so self is self is self. The mutating happens on the original outer self, and the semaphores ensure that everyone does so in an orderly line.

I've run into the same thing when using using a closure wrapper around pthread mutexes for getters and setters inside a struct. Even though the closure parameter is non escaping, the struct (ie `self`) still seems to be treated as an `inout`, so messy things happen.

Answer (score 0):

Value types in iOS are stored in stack and each thread has its own stack. So, in the struct, values will be copied when you access from a different stack. Thanks.